# What questions about allies here, if any, are duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

Currently there exists the following question: "[What does 'ally' mean, as a game term?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129130)" and "[Does a familiar count as an ally?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157995)" was marked as a duplicate. Meanwhile there also exist the following questions:

- [Is a Sentient Weapon considered an ally for the purposes of Pack Tactics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121378)
- [Can charmed foes be considered "allies"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129082)
- [Is a mount considered an "ally" for the purpose of Pack Tactics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121359)
- [Is a creature counted as its own ally?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120915)

None of these are marked as duplicate of the first question I mentioned. Should the question about the familiar not be marked as a duplicate? Or perhaps some of the other questions should be marked as duplicate instead? **What questions here, if any, are duplicates?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think any of those four are duplicates of the more general question. Each of them deals with something specific that can reasonably be expected to complicate the situation so that the answer is non-obvious and merits dedicated expert attention.

- Sentient weapons being allies implies weird interactions with anything (like Pack Tactics) that cares about adjacency
- Mounts counting for Pack Tactics has similar odd interactions
- Charmed is a special circumstance that seems like an ally in some ways and an enemy in others
- Being an ally with yourself in non-obvious and may have odd implications

Each has something that makes a generic question about what “ally” means insufficient.

(By contrast, is your familiar an ally is not a more complicated question: being a familiar introduces nothing unusual that needs to be addressed specifically in a separate, specific question.)